# Creating Visualforce Page Using Tooling API

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

i was trying create a visualforce page from Developer Console using Tooling API ( REST Service ). I checked the documentation it doesn't clarify about the parameters which needs to be present. Whenever i make a call i am getting Status as "Bad Request". I guess i am missing to send some information but i am not able it figure it out.

Please find the code below using which i'm trying to create Visualforce Page.

```
String salesforceHost = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();

String url =  salesforceHost + '/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/ApexPage';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

String classBody = '<apex:page></apex:page>';

req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setBody('{'+
        '"Body" : "' + classBody +'"'+ '"Name" : "MyNewVFPage"' + '}');            

Http http = new Http();

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the below code to create a Page. ApexPage and ApexComponent have `markup` defined and not body. Also there are other fields that are required while creating a page like the `masterLabel` and `controllerType` (this specifies what type of controller is associated with the page i.e., 0=> no Controller, 1=>StandardController, 2=>StandardSet and 3=>custom controller).

```
String salesforceHost = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();

String url =  salesforceHost + '/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/ApexPage';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
//for controllerType = >0 -- no controller
req.setBody('{"Name" : "TestPageFromRest","Markup" : "<apex:page>hello</apex:page>","ControllerType" : "0","MasterLabel":"TestPageFromRest","ApiVersion":"29.0"}');

//for controllerType => 1 -- Standard controller + extensions        
//req.setBody('{"Name" : "TestPageFromRestCase","Markup" : "<apex:page standardController=\'case\' extensions=\'displaycase\'>hello</apex:page>","ControllerType" : "1","MasterLabel":"TestPageFromRestCase","ApiVersion":"29.0"}');

//for controllerType => 3 --custom Controller
req.setBody('{"Name" : "TestPageFromRestCase1","Markup" : "<apex:page controller=\'displaycase\'>hello</apex:page>","ControllerType" : "3","MasterLabel":"TestPageFromRestCase1","ApiVersion":"29.0"}');            
Http http = new Http();

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: Ah great!! Thanks...i tried with Name and Markup ( By looking into ApexPage Class) it didn't work...I Guess other parameters are mandatory then...Is there any document where i can access the information regarding this?

Comment: Actually I figured the mandatory fields by looking at the error message `(res.getBody())`. :)

Comment: Oops...My bad!! I Actually tried it in workbench it was throwing parse error i didn't try to print that in console :)

Comment: Could you please share how we can set the value for ControllerType in case "Standard Controller", "Customer Controller" and "Extension"?...I tried with different set of number as mentioned above and putting appropriate syntax in the markup but it doesn't work

Comment: Even added the added the ControllerKey value to controller name which will be fine...But it doesn't add that in the page attribute. If i try to add then it'll throw parse error.

Comment: Update my answer. Please make sure that the class referred in controller tag is already saved in the org.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...The only issue here is using "" instead ''....if you use "" for Controller or StandardController then we'll get error, which i sadly overlooked