# Error Creating an ApexPage with standardController via ToolingAPI: INVALID_TYPE : sObject type 'Case' is not supported

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api, apexpage, tooling

I am trying to create a ApexPage via Tooling API, that includes a standardController, following this example:
[Creating Visualforce Page Using Tooling API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23599/creating-visualforce-page-using-tooling-api)

However it throws the following error:

```
INVALID_TYPE : sObject type 'Case' is not supported.
```

Can anyone guide me to the proper way to create an ApexPage via Tooling Api that includes a standardController and an Extension?

Comment: We would need to see a sample payload to identify the problem. Can you please **[edit]** your question to show what you've tried so far?